# Why am i getting undefined when accessing a closure variable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I am trying to create a closure within a ReactJS. Within the componentDidMount method I am creating a http request, when the request is complete I would like to access the self variable but I am not able to. It is undefined. Is there anyway to access the self variable?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(self); // undefined
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work when I did the following :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    const newfetch = fetch;
    newfetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(self); // undefined
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems unnecessary given that with arrow functions `this` refers to the lexical scope.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Bill',
  likes: ['cake', 'mars', 'chickens'],
  printLikes() {
    this.likes.forEach((like) => {
      console.log(this.name + " likes " + like);
    });  
  }
};
// => Bill likes cake
// => Bill likes mars
// => Bill likes chickens
```